# Combine text of multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

How to combine text of multiple cells for instance translate this excel formula to VBA code
Cell `F3` should `=Q3&"_"&A3&"_"&D3&"_"&(ROUND(M3/1000,1))&"k"`

But I would Like it to repeat in every instant so in `F99= Q99&"_"&A99&"_"&D99&"_"&(ROUND(M99/1000,1))&"k"`

Using VBA Code:

```
For Each Cel In Range("A1:A100")   
If Cel.Value <> "" Then Cel.Offset(0, 5).Value = *Excel Formula NEED* "Q3&"_"&A3&"_"&D3&"_"&(ROUND(M3/1000,1))&"k""*
```

Saying that if value in column A insert text in same row Column E

Comment: In your formula `""` means nothing, then it is useless in Excel formula and VBA, too. Do you need `" "` (space) instead? The last "k" is just a string or a variable which must be taken from somewhere else? What "*" is used for?

Comment: If you skip the loop and just write the formula to the entire range directly, Excel will update the relative row references.

Comment: ^^ Because you are checking for empty cells, you might just want to use `SpecialCells` to create a range object as @BigBen suggests (or update your formula if you want to write it to the whole column). It's simply a matter of adding a formula to that range object then. If you must (for whatever reason) loop over column A, just `Union` your range and paste a formula in one go.

Comment: What about something like this                                   Sub addtocollumns()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated not seasoned in VBA

Comment: Are these cells in column A actually empty? Or are they empty because they are the result of a formula returning `""`?

Comment: Most cells are empty in column A only header cells have text. So searching for any cell with text in column A

Comment: And does column A have a last used row. With other words, can we find the last used row of your data in column A or do we have to look at another column that has values all the way down?

Comment: Yes there is a last used row but not consistent among different sets of data in one instance last row used is A323. But Data continues to row 329 in different columns

Comment: So which exact column would always have data till the last used row of your data?

Comment: Column's H-O have text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think that a formula (adapted a little to return "" in case of empty cells) would be the best. But, even if you did not answer my question and you want a solution in VBA, please, test the next code:

```
Sub testConcatenate()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, cel As Range, lastRow As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'please use your sheet here
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

  For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    If cel.value <> "" Then
        cel.Offset(0, 5).value = Range("Q" & cel.Row).value & "_" & cel.value & "_"  & _
            Range("D" & cel.Row).value & "_" & Round(Range("M" & cel.Row).value / 1000, 1) & "k"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

You maybe clarify here the meaning of `""` in your formula, what "k" means and what the last character "*" is used for. I did not use it...

Comment: Yes this is working well appreciate your help, how do I add a underscore between Q99 and A99? Them* has no meaning added to signify non code, k is simply the letter to mean thousand, the quotes are used in the excel formula to add the under score no other reason

Comment: @Bay Sherbert: I have to proceed exactly like between Q and D... But I will adapt the code. Added the underscore character.